# I am having a problem running Exodus Wallet on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum

When attempting to run the binary in terminal, I get the following error:

> ./Exodus: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-s.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

1.sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4
2.run exodus

Comment: Can you please [edit] this post to explain what you're doing here and why it'll solve the OP's problem? Please take a look at our [tour] and [answer] pages.

Comment: Many thanks. Seems quite obvious now that I look at it. lol.